# Update inner text of div inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a small hmtml code attached to variable templ. Inside variable templ there is a div with id note-remarks I want to add list of span text something like

```
<small class="note-tag">tag1</small>
```

inside it. Where tag1 is dynamic text. These dynamic text is currently alerted as l. Selected tags are the tags selected while making comment.

```
var tmpl = `<div class="container mb-1">
                {{date('m/d/Y')}}
                <span class="text-gray pull-right">{{Auth::user()->name}}</span>
                <p class="text-gray">
                    <strong>COMMENT</strong>
                </p>
                <div id="note-remarks">
                </div>
            </div>`;
function loadRecentNote(comment,selected_tags){
    $('#recent_note').prepend(tmpl.replace("COMMENT", comment));
    $.each(selected_tags, function( i, l ) {
      alert(l)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var tmpl = `<div class="container mb-1">
              {{date('m/d/Y')}}
              <span class="text-gray pull-right">{{Auth::user()->name}}</span>
              <p class="text-gray">
                <strong>COMMENT</strong>
              </p>
              <div id="note-remarks"></div>
            </div>`;
                
function loadRecentNote(comment, selected_tags) {
  var $tmpl = $(tmpl.replace("COMMENT", comment));  
  $.each(selected_tags, function(i, l) {
    $tmpl.find('#note-remarks').append('<small class="note-tag">' + l + '</small>')
  });  
  $("#recent_note").prepend($tmpl);
}

loadRecentNote('comment', ["tag1", "tag2"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recent_note"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can append all selected tags in a variable and then replace it with html of noter-remarks

```
var tmpl = `<div class="container mb-1">
                            {{date('m/d/Y')}}


                    <span class="text-gray pull-right">{{Auth::user()->name}}</span>
                    <p class="text-gray">
                        <strong>COMMENT</strong>
                    </p>
                    <div id="note-remarks">
                    </div>
                </div>`;
function loadRecentNote(comment,selected_tags){
    $('#recent_note').prepend(tmpl.replace("COMMENT", comment));
    var selectedText = '';
    $.each(selected_tags, function( i, l ){
         //alert(l);
         selectedText += '<small class="note-tag">' + l + '</small>';
        });
      $('#recent_note #note-remarks').html(selectedText);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use `map()` on the array of `selected_tags` to build a HTML string which you can then use to `replace()` a marker in the template; similar to how your logic is currently working for `COMMENT`. Try this:

```js
var tmpl = `
  <div class="container mb-1">
    {{date('m/d/Y')}}
    <span class="text-gray pull-right">{{Auth::user()->name}}</span>
    <p class="text-gray">
      <strong>COMMENT</strong>
    </p>
    <div id="note-remarks">REMARKS</div>
  </div>`;

function loadRecentNote(comment, selected_tags) {
  var remarksHtml = selected_tags.map(function(tag) {
    return `<small class="note-tag">${tag}</small>`;
  }).join('');
  
  var html = tmpl.replace("COMMENT", comment)
  html = html.replace("REMARKS", remarksHtml)
  
  $('#recent_note').prepend(html);
}

loadRecentNote('Comment foo bar', ['tag #1', 'tag #2']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recent_note"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your element, identifying it uniquely and set it to the new value with ".text("arg")" 
jQuery method:

```
$(".note-tag").text("updateText");
```